# Is it possible to add a simple animation in a html template and make it work in all mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, animation

I want to create a template with a simple animation in the logo (e.g. glowing lights, or moving lines). This html template with be submitted via email like a newsletter.
Is it possible accomplish something like this. If so, how? (Will CSS3 transitions do? Or should I go with jQuery?)

Comment: You need CSS keyframe animation, but it's not widely supported

Answer (score 1):

You would like to add an animation in the email template ? If yes, it won't work. Email is very particular, and so different from the web development.

The only way I saw, is to create an gif image with your animation and add the link on the email template.

EDIT : And I am not really sure, that gif works in all email client.